# bin/rails generate -h showing rackup documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I run `bin/rails generate --help` in my rails (5.1.6) project root folder it shows me the help for the rackup command:

```
bin/rails generate --help                                                                                                                                        [±internal/better-admin ●●]
Usage: rackup [ruby options] [rack options] [rackup config]

Ruby options:
  -e, --eval LINE          evaluate a LINE of code
  -b BUILDER_LINE,         evaluate a BUILDER_LINE of code as a builder script
      --builder
  -d, --debug              set debugging flags (set $DEBUG to true)
  -w, --warn               turn warnings on for your script
  -q, --quiet              turn off logging
  -I, --include PATH       specify $LOAD_PATH (may be used more than once)
  -r, --require LIBRARY    require the library, before executing your script

Rack options:
  -s, --server SERVER      serve using SERVER (thin/puma/webrick/mongrel)
  -o, --host HOST          listen on HOST (default: localhost)
  -p, --port PORT          use PORT (default: 9292)
  -O NAME[=VALUE],         pass VALUE to the server as option NAME. If no VALUE, sets it to true. Run 'bin/rails -s SERVER -h' to get a list of options for SERVER
      --option
  -E, --env ENVIRONMENT    use ENVIRONMENT for defaults (default: development)
  -D, --daemonize          run daemonized in the background
  -P, --pid FILE           file to store PID

Common options:
  -h, -?, --help           Show this message
      --version            Show version

Server-specific options for Rack::Handler::Puma:
  -O Threads=MIN:MAX       min:max threads to use (default 0:16)
  -O Verbose               Don't report each request (default: false)
```

`bin/rails generate` alone works fine, but every generate command using a modifier seems to be redirected to the rackup command. So for example `bin/rails generate GENERATOR --anyoption` shows me this:

```
invalid option: --anyoption
Usage: rackup [ruby options] [rack options] [rackup config]
...
```

Has anyone ever encountered this? I already tried disabling spring, but get the same results.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: A sorry. It's MacOS 10.12.6.